# Highlight point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to highlight a single point (always the last) in ggplot2.

I have got most of the way there with the following, however there are a few issues. First, the `color = 'red'` part of the code does not appear to be working, as the point is pink.  Next, the point `red` is added to the legend.

```
testDF <- data.frame('A' = rnorm(547), 'B' = rnorm(547), 
                 'date' = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2013-06-30"), by = 'day'))

testDF$qtrYr <- factor(paste0('q', 
                            as.POSIXlt(testDF$date)$mon %/% 3 + 1, 
                            '-', 
                            as.POSIXlt(testDF$date)$year + 1900
                            ), 
                     levels = c('q1-2012', 'q2-2012', 'q3-2012', 'q4-2012', 'q1-2013', 'q2-2013'),
                     ordered = TRUE)
gp_XY <- ggplot() +
                geom_point(data = subset(testDF, testDF$date > as.Date("2012-04-01")),  
                           aes(x = A, y = 100 * (A - B), color = qtrYr), pch = 1) + 
                    labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) + 
                geom_smooth(data = subset(testDF, testDF$date > as.Date("2012-05-01")),  
                            aes(x = A, y = 100 * (A - B), color = qtrYr), 
                            method = 'lm', se = F, size = 1.25) + 
                geom_point(data = tail(testDF, 1), 
                           aes(x = A, y = 100 * (A - B), color = 'red'), pch = 19, size = 2)
```

Comment: put `color = 'red'` outside `aes()`; like `pch = 19`, it is not an aesthetic mapping, but a set value.

Comment: @baptise probably should be an answer

Comment: it's a duplicate anyway, but such a FAQ that I can't think of search terms for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As commented above:*

You should put `color = 'red'` outside `aes()`; like `pch = 19`, it is not an aesthetic mapping, but a set value.